# Setting process.env variable from Android Studio flavors

Tags: android, react-native, android-flavors

I want to be able to access a variable in my `metro.config.js`.

On iOS this can be achieved by adding a *User Defined* variable in the Build Settings tab. This is accessible with `process.env.MY_VAR`. The value of `MY_VAR` can be changed depending on which target is being built.

How can I achieve the same for Android using product flavours?

Here is my current setup

```
    flavorDimensions "apps"
    productFlavors {
        free {
            dimension "apps"
        }
        paid {
            dimension "apps"
        }
    }
```

**Execution Steps**

When running iOS, I can see from the logs that the project gets built before the Packager starts

```
info Found Xcode workspace "foo.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace foo.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme foo -destination id=CE408502-CD8C-4467-AE3D-295081CAF132 -derivedDataPath build/foo") <-- Build
▸ Running script '[CP-User] Config codegen'
▸ Compiling ReactNativeConfig.m
▸ Building library libreact-native-config.a
▸ Running script 'Upload Debug Symbols to Sentry'
▸ Running script 'Start Packager              <-- Metro starts here
```

However, the packager starts before my gradle build task executes

```
info Starting JS server...                    <-- Metro starts here
info Installing the app...
> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env
> Task :app:installFreeDebug                  <-- Build
```

Comment: use react-native-dotenv

Comment: @divyang4481 - react-native-dotenv provides the ability to read environment variables in JavaScript, I need to access the variable in the Metro Bundler (before any JavaScript gets bundled)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following codes to your `build.gradle` file.

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'KEY_STRING', '"Default_Value"'
    it.buildConfigField 'int', 'KEY_INT', '0'
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.productFlavors[0].ext.has("key_1")) {
        buildConfigField('String', 'KEY_STRING', variant.productFlavors.get(0).ext.key_1)
    }
    if (variant.productFlavors[0].ext.has("key_2")) {
        buildConfigField('int', 'KEY_INT', variant.productFlavors.get(0).ext.key_2)
    }
}
```

and then add `ext.key_1 = '"desired string value"'` and `ext.key_2 = 'desired integer value'` to flavors like this

```
flavorDimensions "apps"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "apps"
        ext.key_1 = '"free_value"'
        ext.key_2 = '0'
    }
    paid {
        dimension "apps"
        ext.key_1 = '"paid_value"'
        ext.ket_2 = '100'
    }
}
```

Now you will access to the values in your app by calling `BuildConfig.KEY_STRING` and `BuildConfig.KEY_INT`.

If you don't set value for `key_1` in a flavor, then the default value will be `"Default_Value"`.

**Update**  
I'm ashamed to say my above answer is wrong because in this way you can access the `BuildConfig` in JS scope but as you mentioned in your question you need to access the configuration in `Metro Bundler` and `metor.config.js`. I added the `console.log(process.env);` at the beginning of `metro.config.js` file and figured out `process.env` in `Metro Bundler` is my OS (in my case Windows 10) environment variables. So it means if you add desired variables as OS environment variable, then you will access them in `metro.config.js` through `process.env`. I tried to add environment variables through `build.gradle` but it wasn't a good way because: 

1. I couldn't find a way to add the environment variable in Gradle

2. If I could do step 1, then as you mentioned the `Metro` starts before android `Build`, so the configuration will be ready late and `Metro` can't access them.

So, I decided to solve this issue in another way. First, I changed the `build.gradle` to log the required variables during Build process.

```
flavorDimensions "apps"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "apps"
        // Add any configuration you need for free flavor
        buildConfigField('String', 'KEY_STRING', '"free_value"')
    }
    paid {
        dimension "apps"
        // Add any configuration you need for paid flavor
        buildConfigField('String', 'KEY_STRING', '"paid_value1"')
        buildConfigField('int', 'KEY_INT', '100')
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    // Read all flavors configuration 
    variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        flavor.buildConfigFields.each { key, value ->
            // Set configuration to variant to be accessible through BuildConfig
            variant.buildConfigField(value.type, value.name, value.value)
            // Log all configurations in output
            println "[" + variant.name + "]---" + value.name + "=" + value.value
        }
    }

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }

}
```

Then I wrote a `bat` file to run `{variant}PreBundle` task (For example freeDebugPreBundle) in Gradle. Then it will read the output and extract required variables and then set them as environment variables and finally call `react-native run-android --variant {variant}` command. 

**run-android.bat**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Reading input arguments to extract desired variant
FOR %%a IN (%*) do (
    set "arg=%%a"
    if "!found!"=="true" (
        set "variant=%%a"
        GOTO:EndOfLoop
    )
    if "!arg!"=="--variant" set found=true
)
:EndOfLoop

:: User must provide variant because when you have flavors, then `debug` varinat does not exist anymore
if "!variant!"=="" (
    echo You must provide --variant
    GOTO:EOF
)

:: Creating a pttern to extract required variables 
set search=[!variant!]---

:: Creating gradle task name based on input variant
set firstCharUpper=%variant:~0,1%
CALL :UpCase firstCharUpper
set taskName=build!firstCharUpper!%variant:~1%PreBundle
echo Running !taskName!

:: Creating an empty bat file to store environment variables and call later
echo. > custome_env.bat

:: Running gradle task and extracting required variables from output log
cd android
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`gradlew app:!taskName!`) DO (
  SET "line=%%F"
  SET "newLine=!line:%search%=!"
  if not "!line!"=="!newLine!" (
    echo !line!
    set "keyValue=!line:%search%=!"
    :: Adding environment variabel to custome_env.bat file
    echo set !keyValue!>>../custome_env.bat
  )
)
ENDLOCAL

:: Running custome_env.bat file to set required variables as environment variable
call custome_env.bat

:: Calling react-native command with all input parameters (%*)
call react-native run-android %*

GOTO:EOF
@echo on

:UpCase
:: Subroutine to convert a variable VALUE to all UPPER CASE.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the variable NAME.
FOR %%i IN ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") DO CALL SET "%1=%%%1:%%~i%%"
GOTO:EOF
```

For running the application you should run this command:

```
run-android.bat --variant freeDebug
```

You can use other `react-native` options as well but you must provide `--variant` because when you have flavors, default variant `debug` does not exist.

**PS:** I don't know how is your release proceseduar, so I'm not sure this answer is compatible with your release procedure or not. if I know it maybe I can find a solution for it.

Comment: Did this answer help?